# Elasticsearch returning both sides of a child parent relationship using multi search query

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

Presently there is no functionality to return both sides of child and parent relationship when searching a child... so the idea is simple, in essence:

1.Search *child document* to return parent using **has_child**
2.Search *only the child* document using a normal searching methods
 
I achieved this:

```
curl -XGET 'IP ADDRESS/elasticsearch/_msearch?pretty=true' -d '{}
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "text",
      "default_field": "text",
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyzer": "std"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "tags_schema": "styled",
    "encoder": "html",
    "fields": {
      "text": {
        "store": true,
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "index_analyzer": "std",
        "number_of_fragments": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "explain": true,
  "size": 1000
}
{}
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "page",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "text": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 1000
}
{}'
```

- however, it's messy and will require a great deal of work to group things and so forth. So I stumbled across this useful post (Slides 41 to 45):
  [Slideshow of a possible programmatic solution for returning both sides of the relationship](https://speakerdeck.com/mvgroningen/document-relations-at-ossc?slide=41)

... So, the aims are as follows, I'm struggling with:

- How I'm to programatically go through each document returned in the has_child to further execute X many queries to get the child documents (as obviously the parent is returned)

Comment: why not get all the parent IDs in first query and then run second query to obtain all children having these parent IDs?

Comment: I'm still fairly new with elasticsearch, would you mind showing an example of how this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up doing this... **Two Stages**.

First Stage - Query the child documents for the search term whilst returning all it's **parent docs *ID's only***

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch?pretty=true' -d' {
"query": {
    "top_children": {
        "type": "page",
         "query":{
             "query_string":{
                 "query":"search string",
                 "default_field":"text",
                 "default_operator":"and"
              }
         },
          "score": "max",
          "factor": 5,
          "incremental_factor": 2
   }
}, 
 "fields":["_id"], 
 "explain":true
}'
```

**Second Stage** - A multisearch query based on the ID's returned

A multi search query can NOT contain spaces, see docs for more information!

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_msearch?pretty=true'  -d '
{Note: These braces are to specify an index or route information}
{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"search string","default_field":"text","default_operator":"and"}},"filter":{"term":{"_parent":"public#627405"}}}},"highlight":{"order":"score","tags_schema":"styled","encoder":"html","fields":{"text":{"store": true,"term_vector": "with_positions_offsets","index_analyzer": "std","number_of_fragments": 0}}}}
{}
{another query}
{}
{another etc}'
```